# Pytorch NN regression model does not learn

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm very new to pytorch and I'm very stuck with model converging. It seems to me it is not learning since the loss/r2 do not improve.

What I've checked/tried based on the suggestions I found here.

1. changes/wrote from scratch loss function
2. set "loss.requires_grad = True"
3. tried to feed the data without dataloader / just straight manual batches
4. played with 2d data / mean pooled data!!! I got decent results for mean pooled data in Random Forest and SVM regressor, but not in NN, which confuses me and makes me think that the data is OK and net is NOT ok!
5. played with learning rate, batch size

etc.

About the data: bert embeddings from letter-sequence, each data point is 1024 features 43 rows (for Conv1d I transpose it to 1024*43)
Total >40K data point in train, batch size=64

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F ## relu, tahn
import torch.utils.data as DataLoader # helps create batches to train on
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import torch.utils.data as data_utils
torch.set_printoptions(precision=10)


#Hyperparameters
learning_rate=0.001
batch_size = 64
num_epochs=100


data_train1 = torch.Tensor(data_train)
targets_train1=torch.Tensor(targets_train)

dataset_train = data_utils.TensorDataset(data_train1, targets_train1)
train_loader = DataLoader.DataLoader(dataset=dataset_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


class NN (nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):#input_size=43x1024
        super(NN,self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(1024, 512, kernel_size=4), #I tried different in and out here
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(512*40, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 1)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)

torch.manual_seed(100)

#Initialize network
model=NN().to(device)

#Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate) #to check 


#Training the model
metric_name='r2'

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    score=[]
    loss_all=[]
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")

    model.train()

    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data=data.to(device=device)
        targets=targets.to(device=device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        #forward
        predictions=model(data)
        
        loss=criterion(predictions,targets).to(device)

        loss.requires_grad = True

        #backward
        loss_all.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
    
        #gradient descent or adam step
        optimizer.step()
        
        #computing r squared
        output=predictions.detach().cpu().numpy()
        target=targets.detach().cpu().numpy()
        output=np.squeeze(output)
        target=np.squeeze(target)
    
        score.append(pearsonr(target, output)[0]**2)

    total_score = sum(score)/len(score)
    print(f'training {metric_name}: {total_score}, mean loss: {sum(loss_all)/len(loss_all)}')
```

Output for (10) first Epochs:
**Epoch: 1/100** training r2: 0.0026224905802415955, mean loss: 0.5084380856556941
**Epoch: 2/100** training r2: 0.0026334153423518466, mean loss: 0.5082988155293148
**Epoch: 3/100** training r2: 0.002577073836564485, mean loss: 0.5085703951569392
**Epoch: 4/100** training r2: 0.002633483899689855, mean loss: 0.5081870414129565
**Epoch: 5/100** training r2: 0.0025642136678393776, mean loss: 0.5083346445680192
**Epoch: 6/100** training r2: 0.0026261540869286933, mean loss: 0.5084220717277274
**Epoch: 7/100** training r2: 0.002614604670602339, mean loss: 0.5082813335398275
**Epoch: 8/100** training r2: 0.0024826257263258784, mean loss: 0.5086268588042153
**Epoch: 9/100** training r2: 0.00261018096876641, mean loss: 0.5082496945227619
**Epoch: 10/100** training r2: 0.002542892071836945, mean loss: 0.5088265852086478

Response is float64 in range (-2,2).

Hope you can help! Thank you in advance for your time!

Update 1. with response scaled to float64 in range [-1,1] and tanh still not converging. I feel like something general is missing. BTW, when I do non shuffled batches and straight-forward data for batches (first batch with indices 0-63, second bath 64-127 etc) I get the same score results in each of epochs!

Update 2. tried to add (2) more sequences with Conv1d, BatchNorm1d, ELU (1024->512, 512->256, 256->128, kernel size 4) and the result is worse:( it is not learning at all!

Comment: What you actually want to predict? That could be the reason too.

Comment: 1 node output with MSE is very unusual and more often than not a bad idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The response is the float64 in (-2,2). What loss would you suggest to try in that case?

Comment: If there's only -2 and 2 then it's a classification problem. If not, make it `(0,1)` and add `sigmoid` or `(-1,1)` and add `tanh`

Comment: Also the model can and should be bigger with more convolution, bn, elu. And better move ELU to after BN

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Thank you! 
Just tried to add (2) more sequences with Conv1d, BatchNorm1d, ELU (1024->512, 512->256, 256->128, kernel size 4) and the result is worse:( it is not learning at all!!!

I will try to rescale response tonight (it is float64 in range (-2,2) so NOT classification) and use another activations.

Comment: with response scaled to  float64 in range [-1,1] and tanh still not converging. I feel like something general is missing. BTW, when I do non shuffled batches and straight-forward data for batches (first batch with indices 0-63, second bath 64-127 etc) I get the same score results in each of epochs!

Comment: The only other things left in my head are using very low lr (like 1e-8). Another is use Linear for first layer and don't transpose. Maybe just Linear and no Conv